# Rest Methods that vary by query string parameters

Tags: .net, wcf

I want to create two Rest methods that vary based on the query string parameter in the URI.

like

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Guest/{guestId}?day={day}&type={type}")]
[OperationContract(Name = "GetDetailByDayAndActivity")]
public GuestDetail GetDetail(string guestId, DateTime day, string type)

[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Guest/{guestId}?day={day}")]
public GuestDetail GetDetail(string guestId, DateTime day)
```

This gives the error:

`"Operation 'GetDetailByDayAndActivity' in contract 'IRestService' has a UriTemplate that expects a parameter named 'TYPE', but there is no input parameter with that name on the operation. "`

When accessing the method that has only the day parameter like: `http://testserver/GuestService/Guest/0?day=2011-10-20`

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured out the cause of this error.
The name of parameter in the Interface was different. The name used in the URI must match with then name in interface.

Moreover, there is no need to define separate methods if we are using query string. Single method would work, in this case other parameters will have null values.

Comment: Dude!! I was having the same problem. Looking at your answer made me realize I was doing the same wrong thing and blaming anything but me!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to map your get params to the resources

Try this one

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Guest/{guestId}/{day}/{type}"
```

Second one

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Guest/{guestId}/{day}"
```

Please notice that you need to change your invocation

Another point change all your signatures to string

For example

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Guest/{guestId}?day={day}")]
public GuestDetail GetDetail(string guestId, **string day**)
```

and than cast to datetime

Comment: This is the requirement that we need to use query string so cannot change it. Regarding signature, date time also worked.

Comment: You only need to use Data type as string when it is part of URI. If it is part of query string, you can use date, int etc.