# Alternate Names for Parameters in REST/WCF Services?

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, rest

Let's say I have a REST Operation Contract in WCF that looks something like this:

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "getXYZ/?LastName={LastName}&BirthDate={BirthDate}&ZipCode={ZipCode}&Year={Year}")]
```

However due to a misunderstanding, some people are passing in "Year" as "BirthYear" and wondering why they're getting errors.  Is there any way I can accommodate this and tell WCF to treat "BirthYear" as "Year" without too much hassle?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the solution you are looking for, but are you able to create a different method that would handle the same parameters except it would use "BirthYear" and pass in these arguements to the regular method in your implementation?

Comment: Near as I can tell an exact overload in WCF/Rest is not possible, or in my example sure I could create a new UriTemplate and Function for "BirthYear" but then my UriTemplate would have to specify getABC for the directory, or something different, no?

Comment: I think you should be able to use the same string in your interface. Just make sure your parameter names are correct.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162621/rest-methods-that-vary-by-query-string-parameters